# Convert string into integer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, form-for

I'm creating a form_for in which one of the field fetches the drop-down list from the database. I'm interpolating the data to display the string but I want to store its id back into other database which is linked with my form.

---

```
class FlightsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @flight = Flight.new
    @airplane = @flight.airplane
    @options = Airport.list
  end

  def create
    @flight = Flight.new(flight_params)
    if @flight.save!
      flash[:success] = "Flight created successfully."
      redirect_to @flight
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Flight not created."
      redirect_to :new
    end
  end

  private

    def flight_params
      params.require(:flight).permit(:name, :origin, :destination, :depart, :arrive, :fare, :airplane_id)
    end
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for(@flight) do |f| %>
  ...
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :origin %>
      <%= f.select :origin, grouped_options_for_select(@options), { include_blank: "Any", class: "form-control selectpicker", data: { "live-search": true } } %>
    </div>
  </div>
...
<% end %>
```

---

```
class Airport < ApplicationRecord
  def self.list
    grouped_list = {}
    includes(:country).order("countries.name", :name).each do |a|
      grouped_list[a.country.name] ||= [["#{a.country.iso} #{a.country.name}", a.country.iso]]
      grouped_list[a.country.name] << ["#{a.iata} #{a.name} (#{a.city}, #{a.country.name})", a.id]
    end
    grouped_list
  end
end
```

---

```
class Flight < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :origin, class_name: "Airport"
  belongs_to :destination, class_name: "Airport"
  belongs_to :airplane
  has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :passengers, through: :bookings
end
```

---

The following error is showing,

> `Airport(#69813853361360) expected, got "43" which is an instance of String(#47256130076180)`

---

The output of `Airport.list` when run in a console is shown below:

```
=> {"India"=>[["IN India", "IN"], ["AGX Agatti Airport (Agatti, India)", 3], ["IXV Along Airport (Along, India)", 5], ["AML Aranmula International Airport (Aranmula, India)", 6], ["IXB Bagdogra International Airport (Siliguri, India)", 50]]}
```

---

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+Z8+rkrJkkgaTznnwyTd/QjEoq3kR4ZmoUTp+EpM+320fNFg5rJm+Izx1zBODo/H7IIm3D+yg3ysnVUPmy7ZwQ==", "flight"=>{"name"=>"Indigo", "origin"=>"49", "destination"=>"11", "depart"=>"2019-02-21T21:30", "arrive"=>"2019-02-22T01:30", "fare"=>"2500", "airplane_id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Create Flight"}
```

---

I tried using `to_i` but it didn't work.

Comment: what you see in a params in console ?

Comment: Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"+Z8+rkrJkkgaTznnwyTd/QjEoq3kR4ZmoUTp+EpM+320fNFg5rJm+Izx1zBODo/H7IIm3D+yg3ysnVUPmy7ZwQ==",
 "flight"=>{"name"=>"Indigo", "origin"=>"49", "destination"=>"11", "depart"=>"2019-02-21T21:30", "arrive"=>"2019-02-22T01:30", "fare"=>"2500", "airplane_id"=>"3"},
 "commit"=>"Create Flight"}

Comment: origin and destination have string format in params but database column is of type bigint.

Comment: try replace origin to origin_id on your f.select and update a params

Comment: It gives the error - Origin must exist, Destination must exist. I think it is because they are the foreign keys from Airport.

Comment: Can you please add codebase of Flight model ass well?

Comment: Sure, I have added that...

Answer (score 1):

if you're interpolating a string with space delimiter you can try this.

```
'1 one'.split(' ').first.to_i
```

Comment: No, actually my drop-down shows the list of airports but when I submit the form it should store its id in integer format instead it is returning id in string format hence couldn't store it

Comment: instead of using `grouped_options_for_select` try this `options_for_select` for displaying dropdown values in view

Comment: flight_params are listed in the controller under private

Comment: i know that! I requested you to upload those params data when you're creating

Comment: I can't use options_for_select because I need to group multiple data and display it as a single record.

Comment: yeah but you're interpolating all the data right? And sending this format `[[data, id], [data, id]...]`. So, i think you can use  `options_for_select`. If not that update output of `Airport.list` if possible

Comment: Yeah, I'm interpolating the data. When I tried options_for_select it returns only the country. How exactly the output of Airport.list be updated?

Comment: in you're question update the output of `Airport.list` by running it in console you'll get that output

Comment: are you displaying dropdown data based on country selected?

Comment: Yeah but currently I have added only one country

Comment: okay then `options_for_select` will not work you have to use `grouped_options_for_select` and also in you're params origin & destination keys are to be like this `origin_id => 1, destination_id => 2` hence you're getting this error `Origin must exist, Destination must exist`

Answer (score 0):

`grouped_options_for_select` is sending `a.id` as string value. Convert it to integer in your create action.

```
def create
    @flight = Flight.new(flight_params)
    @flight.origin = @flight.origin.to_i  ## <== add this line
    if @flight.save!
    ...
```

Comment: Bro, I tried this already (as mentioned in the question) but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Convert string into integer in rails:

```
user_id = "123"

@user_id = user_id.to_i

puts @user_id

@user_id = 123
```

Convert integer into string in rails:

```
user_id = 456

@user_id = user_id.to_s

puts @user_id

@user_id = "456"
```

Convert column type string into integer in rails migration :

```
def change
  change_column :webinars, :user_id, :integer, using: 'user_id::integer'
end
```

Convert column type integer into string in rails migration:

```
 def change
   change_column :webinars, :user_id, :string, using: 'user_id::string'
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not integer versus string, your problem is (and the error is telling you) the field is expecting an Airport object, but it's getting an airport id...

```
<%= f.select :origin, grouped_options_for_select(@options), { include_blank: "Any", class: "form-control selectpicker", data: { "live-search": true } } %>
```

You're trying to select `origin` which is an airport object. You really are just returning the ID of an airport object (`origin_id`).

Change it to

```
<%= f.select :origin_id, grouped_options_for_select(@options), { include_blank: "Any", class: "form-control selectpicker", data: { "live-search": true } } %><%= f.select :origin, grouped_options_for_select(@options), { include_blank: "Any", class: "form-control selectpicker", data: { "live-search": true } } %>
```

And don't forget to update your flight_params

```
def flight_params
  params.require(:flight).permit(:name, :origin_id, :destination, :depart, :arrive, :fare, :airplane_id)
end
```

I would guess  you'll have a similar problem with `destination`